# Где ошибся в выражении php Modx

Tags: php, cms, modx

есть условие :

```
$cost = $miniShop2->order->getCost();
$order['cost'] = $miniShop2->formatPrice($cost['data']['cost']);
$order['maxprice'] = $maxprice;


$str = $order['cost'];
$str = str_replace(' ', '', trim($str));
$str = intval($str, 'integer');


if ($str < 5000){
  $order['priznak'] = 1;  
}else{
   $order['priznak'] = 0;  
}
```

но все ровно выводит 1, число 5000 сравнивается с числом на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш пхп должен на этом коде писать Warning, если его нет (вывод ошибок отключен?) — понастраивайте пхп как-нибудь так, чтоб появился

Answer (score 1):

1. Убери второй параметр в `intval()`

Получится что-то вроде `$str = intval($str);`

2. Я бы еще чуть упростил принцип присвоения `$data['prinak']`

Вместо ветвления `if -- else` сделал бы так:

```
$data['priznak'] = 0;
if($str < 5000){
    $data['priznak'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, убрал второй параметр и заработало

Comment: Можно вообще `(int)$str` писать

Comment: @DaemonHK в данном случае можно. Но есть одно небольшое различие между intval() и (int).... Оно в возможности задать основание системы счисления.... Мало ли...